# Where do I call my custom controller method in code igniter when session expires automatically?

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

I am using `CI` version `3.1.7`.

I am elaborating my requirement below:

I want to execute the query and update the field value of the database when the CodeIgniter session expires.

right now my application is redirecting to the login page when the session expires which is correct but I just want to place one update query before it redirects when the session time is over.

I am using the file as a session driver.

I have written a custom class in the `application/core` folder which is overriding the `sess_destroy()` method of session library. but it seems to be not working

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Session extends CI_Session
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }
    function sess_destroy() {
        //My update queries will go here 

        //call the parent 
        parent::sess_destroy();
    }
}
```

Please help me to get rid of this.

Comment: [`sess_destroy()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#destroying-a-session) is called when you want to destroy the session - eg on logout.  That's not what happens when the session just expires.  I am not sure how to detect an expired session - eg when a request comes in without a valid session, how can you tell if it is from an expired session, or a brand new session?  Unless you check timestamps etc after login ...

Comment: that is what the main issue is I can could not able to detect an expired session.. I tried debugging the session library. but no luck. 

In fact could not able to catch which method is being executed when session automatically expires

Answer (score 0):

You can manage session expiration in the constructor of each controller or you can create a Base custom control which extends CI_Controller class. In that base controller you can use your "MY_Session" as a library.

With this approach for every request base class constructor will check for session and if it fails you can override the actions that you want to perform.